# Script continues reading from file although file is finished

Tags: python

I am creating script which reads from rockyou.txt file and the problem is that when it finishes going through all lines - 1.5M then it continues reading empty lines from the file and i need it to stop.

I can't do a simple if statement to check if the line is empty because in the file there are multiple places where there is a single empty line.

Do you have any ideas how to implement?

Code:

```
while line != static:
    line = f.readline()
    line = line.strip()
    counter = counter + 1

    print("Trying " + line + " Number " + str(counter))
if line == static:
    print("Success")
    flag = 1
    break
if flag == 0:
    print("Unsuccessful")
```

Comment: What’s `static`? Apparently whatever it is it isn’t found in the file.

Comment: don't loop over a file like this. Use `for line in f: ...` that will terminate automatically when you reach the end fo a file. Otherwise, you'd need to ask `if line == '': break` right after `line = f.readline()`, or make it part of the loop condition, but again **don't loop over a file like this to begin with**

Comment: If the loop should stop at the end of the file, make sure it is part of the loop condition...

Comment: I think he is saying the file has empty lines in itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code attempts to read lines until a hit is found, but it doesn’t test whether the end of the file is reached.

Rewrite your code as follows to stop at the end of the file:

```
found = False

for line in f:
    if line.strip() == static:
        found = True
        break
```

This code is omitting the counter, but it could be added back in trivially:

```
for counter, line in enumerate(f, 1):
    line = line.strip()
    print(f'Trying {line} Number {counter}')

    if line == static:
        found = True
        break
```

Comment: perhaps `enumerate(f, 1)` but +1

Comment: Thank you, it works and i feel like this is more appropriate way to go through a file

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single blank line, `readline()` will actually return `"\n"` rather than an empty string `""`. Thus it is safe to do this:

```
line = f.readline()
if not line:
    break
```

Since `bool('\n') is True`. No blank lines will be skipped.

Comment: It may be safe but it’s definitely not the idiomatic way of looping over lines in a file.

Comment: @KonradRudolph True, though it would be the smallest change necessary to make the code work

Comment: @KonradRudolph Still, it clearly explains the issue in the original question and there is no telling what the rest of the original code looks like.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of checking for 1 single empty line, check for multiple single lines. You can do this by setting another counter like this

```
emptyLineCounter = 0

while True:
  if line == '': #Because it has been stripped,there will be no extra empty spaces
     emptyLineCounter+=1
     if emptyLineCounter==2: #Or any number of lines you want it to be
        break
  else:
     emptyLineCounter = 0 #Resetting it to zero if there is text in the line
```

Comment: It’s not clear how this is supposed to answer OP’s question.

Comment: Uhmm I think it is. I have explained how he can check if the code is reading multiple empty lines in a row

Comment: But that isn’t the question. The question is how to stop reading at the end of the file.